# Artifactory REST API and artifact license

Tags: rest, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm new to artifactory REST API and AQL specific language.

I would like to build a list of dependencies like this

`moduleId:ArtifactId:VersionId:License`

I'm able to get dependencies for one build via `GET /api/build/<name>/<id>`, I could do a script to extract each dependencies, but I don't know how to ask license?

I succeed to get list of dependencies with AQL and print license.

```
items.find(
    {"dependency.module.build.name": "foo" }    
  ).include("name", "repo", "path", "@artifactory.licenses")
```

Issue now is that if there is no license property set, dependencies is not returned.

Any help?

Thanks by advance.